# Python Prevent input text from being seperated from other text

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, input, terminal

Recently I have been looking into creating a chat room in `python3`. I have been experimenting with receving/printing incoming messages and receiving an input at the same time using threads and was trying to figure out how to prevent incoming text writing over the user's input and splitting it onto different lines. Here is an example of what I mean:

```py
import threading
import time
import sys

def show_message(msg):
        while True:
                sys.stdout.write(msg + "\n")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(2)

t = threading.Thread(target=show_message, args=("Example Message",))
t.start()

while True:
        msg = input("Your message>")
        print(f"<You> {msg}")
```

When running this, it successfully prints out `"Example Message"` over and over again via a thread and the input works when pressing the return key and outputs `<You> [the message input]` but  gets overwritten and splits the input onto multiple lines because of the `"Example Message"`. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening and keep the input line on the top or bottom on the terminal without incoming messages reaching the line and splitting it/overwriting it?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate it under linux with zsh. Try an online compiler and see if you can replicate it there.

Comment: @BruceShen Oh thats strange, are you sure you're using python3 and not python2?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6. Since I can't replicate it, I would just guess the reason is two different printing methods used. `print` is buffered and handled by python. `stdout.write` is more low-level and invoke the syscall directly.

Comment: @BruceShen Thanks for your replies. On my system the code runs ok, im just wondering if theres anyway to not overwrite the input line which then splits the user's keystrokes to multiple lines. I use `sys.stdout.write` too

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I think you can achieve the effect that keeps "Example Message" on top. The input cursor is always on the last line

Comment: @BruceShen Ive tried using some ANSI strings to print on top and bottom but after the terminal fills up, the same thing happens unfortunately :(

Comment: Curses library may contain something you need. `https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html`. You will probably end up with a single thread controlling the output. Not that all threads can output to stdout.